# Add parameter to the action filter from service filter

Tags: c#, .net-core, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I am using a service filter attribute in the controller. From the service filter, I called the Action filter and inside the action filter, I do the action methods like `OnActionExecution`.

My case is passing the parameter from the controller. Using that parameter, I need to do the necessary actions in the action filter class.

**Controller**

```
[HasPermission(1)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetDetailsAsync()
{
  -----
}
```

**Service Filter**

```
 public class HasPermissionAttribute : ServiceFilterAttribute
    {
        public HasPermissionAttribute()
            : base(typeof(HasPermissionAsyncFilter))
        {
        }
    }
```

**Action filter**

```
 public class HasPermissionAsyncFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
 {
       public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
       {
           -------------Need to use the values passed from the attribute-------
       }
 }
```

**Note:**

Need to pass the values in the attribute

HasPermission(1)

HasPermission(2)

Like this......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [TypeFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typefilterattribute) that is alike `[ServiceFilterAttribute]` but allows you to pass arguments:

```
public class HasPermissionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute // Changed parent class
{
    public HasPermissionAttribute(int value)
        : base(typeof(HasPermissionAsyncFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { value };
    }
}

public class HasPermissionAsyncFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly int _permissionValue;

    public HasPermissionAsyncFilter(int permissionValue)
    {
        _permissionValue = permissionValue;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // -------------Need to use the values passed from the attribute-------
        var x = _permissionValue;
    }
}
```